# How to use an alias when creating sphinx autodoc for python packages?

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a folder structure for my python package something on these lines:

```
mypackage
├── subpackage1
│   ├── _somefunctions.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── subpackage2
│   ├── _classFunc.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── __init__.py
```

in `mypackage.__init__.py` file I have written something like

```py
from . import subpackage1 as sp1
from . import subpackage2 as sp2
```

In my sphinx documentation I would want these subpackage to be

1. Listed under the submodules part when running autodoc
2. instead of listing the subpackage1, can this be listed as `mypackage.sp1` and `mypackage.sp2`

I tried doing this but it didn't work:

`sphinx-apidoc --implicit-namespaces -f -e -o docs/source spatialDNA/`